# How to pass the parameters of constructor while instantiating a class in a new JVM instance using ProcessBuilder?

Tags: java, parameters, processbuilder

I need to instantiate a new class from an existing class in a new JVM. I am using `ProcessBuilder` to do this but, the problem is that I have to pass a parameter to the constructor of this new class. Where do I specify the constructor's parameter using Process Builder.

This is what am doing currently but, I need to send a value from this class to the new class in the new JVM.

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(Javabin, "-cp", 
        classpath, NewJVM.class.getName());
```

Comment: You need to pass it through the new class's `main(String[] args)` method.

Comment: yes, add the parameters after the class name

Comment: Okay Thankyou @MauricePerry and Klitos Kyriacou but what if the parameter is not a string and is an object of another class.

Comment: You need to convert them into strings in one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameter in ProcessBuilder and the parameter type should be of type String.Any way it will call main method and required parameter is string  which will be a entry point .You can put your logic in a driver class which will call by main method.

```
 Process process = new ProcessBuilder(
                System.getProperty("java.home") + "/bin/java",
                "-classpath",
                classpath,
                MyMainClass.class.getCanonicalName()
                // main class arguments go here
        )
```